# strange dropdown list in Magento 1.6.1.0 search box

Tags: magento, google-chrome, magento-1.6

I have this list (see attached) appearing below the search box on my Magento site - url http://www.performplay.co.uk , I have checked the db for these search terms but they are not in the db. I have re-indexed and cleared the cache but they still appear - I have done this from the back-end - not using the script indexer.php.

Not sure what is causing this list top appear seems to be in Chrome not IE ..?

Any ideas

Thanks [image]

Comment: What's wrong with it? That is an autocomplete for your search term. Use firebug and there must be an ajax request for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your styles.css (skin/frontend/default/perform-play/css/styles.css) is not complete. Insert something like:

```
#search_autocomplete ul {
    background: #ffffff; 
    position: absolute;
}

#search_autocomplete ul .amount {
    color: #00FF00;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 9px 0 0 9px;
}
```